# For cp command, how to understand the "newer" file

Tags: linux, cp

I checked `man cp` and did some experiments in Ubuntu 14.04. I found that `cp -u` updates files by comparing the modification time. Am I correct? In the man page it states:

> **-u, --update**
>   copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

I just can't find the definition of "newer", do we compare access time, modification time or change time in general case?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why the target should be updated, when metadata changes ("changes") occur to the source, like renaming, additional hard links or whatever. So it is to be expected that only content changes ("modifications") count.

I just tested this by creating a source file, copying to the target, renaming the source and repeating the copy.

When listing the files according to last metadata changes with `ls -ltc` the timestamp was newer for the source file. So no copying although the source is newer concerning "changes". Changes in the content lead to the expected update of the target.

Just a short note: renaming changes the modification time, which is in fact not really obvious, as the files name is stored in the directory, not in the inode. But when renaming the kernel creates a new hard link of the inode in question and deletes the one pointing to the old name. So although the number of hard links stored in the inode is the same before and after the renaming operation, the inode has in fact changed twice.

The same result can be achieved with changes where the effect on the inode is more obvious like `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked **core-utils** [source files](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) for `--update` option, and now i can answer it once for all. When you use `-u` or `--update` option to your `cp` command - it is used in copy.c on line 1662:

```
if (0 <= utimecmp (dst_name, &dst_sb, &src_sb, options))
```

As you can see it's using additional function, that's comparing file information. Now we only need to now how `utimecmp` works. It's code is available [here](http://fossies.org/dox/coreutils-8.23/utimecmp_8c_source.html), and that is what is comparing:

```
time_t dst_s = dst_stat->st_mtime;
time_t src_s = src_stat->st_mtime;
int dst_ns = get_stat_mtime_ns (dst_stat);
int src_ns = get_stat_mtime_ns (src_stat);
```

Surely it is **modification time**. You were right! :)